# WMQ JMS provider version

Tags: jms, version, ibm-mq, provider

I have a new WMQ 7.5.0.2 server on a new machine

I have a client jar, taht include WMQ client jars

I replaced the old client jars with the 7.5.0.2 jars into my master client jar

```
   com.ibm.mq.jar
   dhbcore.jar
   com.ibm.mq.headers.jar
   com.ibm.mq.jmqi.jar
   com.ibm.mqjms.jar
```

However, when I run my client, I see the following:

```
JMS Provider Name=IBM WebSphere MQ 
Provider Version=7.0.0.0 
Provider Major Version=7 
Provider Minor Version=0
```

I am sure the program is connecting to the correct, and that the new client jars are 7.5.0.2

Am I correct in believing that the Product Version should be 7.5.0.2 instead of

```
Provider Version=7.0.0.0
```

I need to ensure I am using the correct jar files,  how should I proceed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Provider Version=7.0.0.0

Where did you get that information from?

Note: Your queue manager may be v7.0.0.0 and your client application may be using v7.5.0.2 JAR files.